# How to retrieve selected row from datagridview and store in DataTable

Tags: c#, sql

I have Datagridview .. selected a row .i want that row to be added to my list in other form

Comment: what have you done so far, and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I wish to take those datagridview row in datable.. im not able to do..Arugment exception i find

Comment: it would help if you showed the code you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the OnClick event handler and then add the selected row into your List.